# Magento 2, shipping method flat rate fix price with the current website currency, without converting to the base currency?

Tags: magento2

Magento 2, shipping method flat rate fix price with the current website currency, without converting to the base currency?

What I'm trying to do is to set the flat rate currency to the current website display currency and not convert it to the base currency.
is that possible in Magento 2? and how can I achieve that?

thanks

Comment: Any solution for this ?